# Translating a word with locotranslate, but wordpress does display another by default

Tags: translation

I use wpadverts plugin and Loco translate to translate the plugin.

I'm trying to translate from English to French the "Email" word to "Email" :D. When I translate the word in LocoTranslate plugin, it look fine, and when i try to display it in frontend all my other words are well displayed but the only once who is not well displayed is Email. Wordpress display me "Adresse de contact"  instead of "Email".

Here is a screenshot from frontend with a print_r():

[image]

So, we can see that my label has been translated and called but replaced (maybe) by wordpress core.

But if I make a main search in my wordpress folders, I can't find where is these coming from.

Did someone had the same issue or any Idea from where is this coming from?

Thank you :D

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

Wordpress default translation were overriding my translation string.

In locotranslate plugin go to settings and click on : Activate the main translation from wordpress.

And than you can find and edit your specific string who is overrided.